# ImmutableList vs List- what should I cast it as?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I know its commonly accepted to cast all `List` implementations down to `List`. Whether it is a variable, method return, or a method parameter using an `ArrayList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, etc.

```
List<Market> mkts = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I'm using a Guava `ImmutableList`, I have the sense it can arguably be an exception to this rule (especially if I'm building in-house, complicated business applications and not a public API). Because if I cast it down to list, the deprecated mutator methods will no longer be flagged as deprecated. Also, it no longer is identified as an immutable object which is a very important part of its functionality and identity.

```
List<Market> mkts = ImmutableList.of(mkt1,mkt2,mkt3);
```

Therefore it makes sense to pass it around as an `ImmutableList` right? I could even argue that its a good policy for an internal API to only accept `ImmutableList`, so mutability and multithreading on the client side won't wreck anything inside the libary.

```
ImmutableList<Market> mkts = ImmutableList.of(mkt1,mkt2,mkt3);
```

I know there is a risk of `ImmutableList` itself becoming deprecated, and the day Oracle decides to create its own `ImmutableList` will require a lot of refactoring. But is it arguable the pros of maintaining an `ImmutableList` cast can outweigh the cons?

Comment: In this case, I will use `ImmutableList<Whatever>` directly. Ongoing refactoring in case such class is implemented by Oracle should not worry you, otherwise we all be afraid of changes in the future and code won't be produced.

Comment: Very well spoken, Luiggi. And when I implement an `ImmutableList`, I have rarely encountered a need to switch it to a mutable list implementation later. When I make something immutable, the entire structure of the application is built and optimized around the fact it is immutable.

Comment: Another option could be to use `List<? extends Market>` as the list's type. It will give you a little bit of compiler-enforced immutability--you can't call `mkts.add(new Market())` for example. But this does not declare the intention as well as `ImmutableList`

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519105/use-of-guava-immutable-collection-as-method-parameter-and-or-return-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with your rationale.  If you are using the Guava collection library and your lists are immutable then passing them as `ImmutableList` is a good idea.

However:

> I know there is a risk of ImmutableList itself becoming deprecated, and the day Oracle decides to create its own ImmutableList will require a lot of refactoring.

The first scenario seems unlikely, but it is a risk you take whenever you use *any* 3rd-party library.  But the flipside is that you could chose to not upgrade your application's Guava version if they (Google) gratuitously deprecated a class or method that you relied on.

**UPDATE**

Louis Wasserman (who works for Google) said in a comment:

> "Guava provides pretty strong compatibility guarantees for non-@Beta APIs."

So we can discount the possibility of gratuitous API changes.

---

The second scenario is even more unlikely (IMO).  And you can be sure that if Oracle did add an immutable list class or interface, that would not *require* you to refactor.  Oracle tries really hard to avoid breaking existing code when they enhance the standard APIs.

But having said that, it is really up to you to weigh up the pros and cons ... and how you would deal with the cons should the eventuate.

Comment: Oracle and Guava also talk to each other about these things, for reference, and Guava provides pretty strong compatibility guarantees for non-@Beta APIs.

Comment: There's another bonus; the Immutable* classes override all mutative methods from the core collections interfaces (add, put, etc) to mark them deprecated.  So if you use the Immutable* types for your variables, your IDE will warn you if you try to call list.add(something).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no corresponding interface in Java (and most probably never will be). So my take is to pretend that `ImmutableList` is an interface. :D But seriously, it add important information which shouldn't get lost.

The ancient rule it all comes from actually states something like "program against interfaces". IIRC at the time the rules was created, there was no Java around and "interface" means programming interface, i.e., the contract, not java `interface`.

A method like

```
void strange(ArrayList list) {...}
```

is obviously strange, as there's no reason not to use `List`. A signature containing `ImmutableList` has a good reason.

---

> I know there is a risk of ImmutableList itself becoming deprecated, and the day Oracle decides to create its own ImmutableList will require a lot of refactoring.

You mean Java 18? Let's see, but Guava's `ImmutableList` is pretty good and there's not much point in designing such a class differently. So you can hope that most changes will be in your imports only. And by 2050 there'll be worse problems than this.

Answer (score 2):

**Keep using `List` rather than `ImmutableList`!** There is no problem with that and no reason for your API to start using `ImmutableLists` explicitly for several reasons:

1. `ImmutableList` is Guava only and unlikely to become standard Java at any point. Don't tie your code and coding habits to a third party library (even if it is a cool one like Guava).
2. Using immutable objects is good practice in Java and of particular importance when developing an API (see Effective Java Item 15 - minimize mutability). It is a general concept that can be taken for granted and does not need to be conveyed in the name of interfaces. Equally, you would not consider calling a User class that is designed for inheritance `UserThatCanBeSubclassed`.
3. In the name of stability your API should NEVER start modifying a `List` that was passed into it and ALWAYS make a defensive copy when passing a `List` to a client. Introducing `ImmutableList` here would lure you and the clients of your API into a false sense of security and entice them to violate that rule.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your dilemma.

Personnaly, I would advise to keep using `List` as the reference type (to be future-proof and benefit from polymorphism), and use an `@Immutable` annotation to convey the information that it is immutable.

Annotations are more visible than plain javadoc comments, and you can even use the one from [JSR-305](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/) (ex-JCIP). 
Some static analysis tools can even detect it and verify that your object is not mutated.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather stay with just `List` for method parameter. There is no much benefit to enforce the caller to pass `ImmutableList` - it's your own method and you won't mutate list anyway, but you'd have method more reusable and generic.

As a return type, I would go with `ImmutableList` to let method users know that this list cannot be modified.