# Enforce specific Map implementation in Immutables

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap, immutables-library

I am using [Immutables](http://immutables.github.io/) Java library, how can I enforce a specific map implementation, without having to use a specific reference?

```
@Immutable
public interface ConfigIF {
  Map<String, String> getOptions();
}
```

If I use the above code the concrete `Map` is a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
@Immutable
public interface ConfigIF {
  TreeMap<String, String> getOptions();
}
```

If I use the above code both the reference and the implementations are `TreeMap`.

Is there a way to specify `Map` as a reference but enforce `TreeMap` as concrete type?

Comment: Almost certainly not.  You'll need to do the second thing.

Comment: Something you may also find useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9521003/3708426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not - and it should be forbidden (that is : no option given to you as a user to alter that). This is not specific to your library, but any code in general that returns a `Map` instead of `TreeMap` let' say.

Look it the other way, if you return a `Map` users are not expect to call `ceilingEntry` on it (that is available in `TreeMap`, but not in `Map`) via cast of the reference.

java-8 does the same thing when via it's `Collectors.toXXX`. For example `Collectors.toList` explicitly says:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned.

This means that they are allowed to return whatever they find the most appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I only don't get how they can return something appropriate when the user is the only one that knows what implementation will be beneficial.

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo the choice is almost always a series of compromises between speed, memory, etc. Or even an internal data structure that will perform things faster, like `toArray` in java-8 that uses `SpinedBuffer`...